# What is an ice circle, and how does it form?

Tags: rivers, ice

I've seen ice do a lot of strange things, but I've never seen it do this before: [Ice Circle spinning on Middle Fork Snoqualmie River (Vimeo)](https://vimeo.com/198519875).

[image: ice circle]

What causes ice circles to form?

Comment: See also [EarthScience.SE] SE, which I believe would be a better fit for this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Ice Disk

That phenomenon is called an ice disc or ice circle. It occurs in slow moving water in cold climates.

> Ice discs form on the outer bends in a river where the accelerating
>   water creates a force called 'rotational shear', which breaks off a
>   chunk of ice and twists it around. As the disc rotates, it grinds
>   against surrounding ice — smoothing into a circle.

<sub>From [Wikipedia - Ice Circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_circle)</sub>

### Your Ice Circle

This particular ice disk (from your video), was formed because there was a certain climate which is perfect for such phenomenon to build.

> "Calm winds this week combined with 6 mornings in a row in the low 20s
>   made for perfect conditions to form the circles," said Q13 Chief
>   Meteorologist Walter Kelley.

<sub>From [Fox4KC](http://fox4kc.com/2017/01/09/rare-ice-circle-forms-in-washington-state-river/)</sub>

### Why is it so rare?

> (...) but I've never seen it do this before(.)

The occurrence of such are absolutely rare since you have to face perfect really specific conditions (water, climate, river etc.).

> Ice circles or disc are a relatively uncommon phenomenon. One of the
>   earliest recordings is of a slowly revolving disc spotted on the
>   Mianus River in 1895.

<sub>From [Fox4KC](http://fox4kc.com/2017/01/09/rare-ice-circle-forms-in-washington-state-river/)</sub>

> An unusual natural phenomenon, ice disks occur in slow moving water in
>   cold climates and can vary in size, with circles more than 15 metres
>   (49 ft) in diameter observed.

<sub>From [Wikipedia - Ice Circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_circle)</sub>

### Further reading

- [MIT News - Theories abound on how the river got those patterns](http://news.mit.edu/1993/river-0224)
- [Ice Disc Blogpost](http://digg.com/video/ice-circle-river)